# how to rename NSArrayController in XCode 4.2?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, rename, nsarraycontroller

Is there a way to rename an instance of NSArrayController in XCode 4.2? I'm asking cause there are some tutorials implementing it and one of the steps is to rename 'Array Controller' to something else but authors seems to be using older version of XCode where it works with just one click. Is it possible in latest version?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to say this is likely a bug. Previous versions (including major versions where Interface Builder was a separate app) did allow you to rename renamable objects by single-clicking their labels. That suddenly stopped working and there's no good reason why. If you want it back, file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can rename it by changing its label in identity inspector !

As shown in image below :

[image]